# edittext with setOnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 9 edittext I want when we insert a value in an edittext and this number exists in another edittext and a message is displayed for example if I type 4 in et0 and 4 already insert in another editext a message of type setError ("you can use 4 only one") 
[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {

                ic = et2.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
                keyboard.setInputConnection(ic);
            } else {
                for (String text : texts) {
                    if (et2.getText().toString().equals(et1.getText().toString()) ||
                            (et2.getText().toString()).equals(et3.getText().toString()) ||
                            (et2.getText().toString().equals(et4.getText().toString())) ||
                            (et2.getText().toString().equals(et5.getText().toString())) ||
                            et2.getText().toString().equals(et6.getText().toString()) ||
                            et2.getText().toString().equals(et7.getText().toString()) ||
                            et2.getText().toString().equals(et8.getText().toString()) ||
                            et2.getText().toString().equals(et9.getText().toString())) {
                        if (et2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            return;
                        }


                        et2.setError((CharSequence) text);
                        et2.setText("");
                        afficheerr1();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

same thing for other edittext

Comment: And what is your problem/question ?

Comment: I want to put the edittexts in an arraylist then I display the number that repeats itself
in et2.setError

Comment: still what is your question/problem ? You don't know how to put them in arraylist ? you don't know how to find repeated number ? you don't know how to set et2 ?

Comment: Yes exactly I am a beginner in this field

Comment: Please edit your post to ask a precise question